# How to generate a simple class with T4?

Tags: c#, templates, code-generation, t4

I'm working on a VSPackage that's supposed to generate simple classes from some data in a DB. I already have a static method `GetFieldInfo` that gets the data I need from the DB, and `GetFieldInfo` returns me a `List<TableField>` where `TableField` is a custom class that holds all the data I need.

So far, my T4 template looks like this:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Threading.Tasks" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>
<#@ parameter name="namespace" type="System.String" #>
<#@ parameter name="className" type="System.String" #>
<#@ parameter name="fields" type="System.Collections.Generic.List<TableField>" #>

namespace <#= this.namespace #>
{
    public class <#= classname #>
    {
        <#
            foreach (TableField campo in fields)
            {

            }
        #>
    }
}
```

All this (the static method, the custom class and the template) are in different namespaces inside the same project. This project (let's call it "the helper project") is not the VSPackage project (it's added as a reference in the VSPackage one).

My problem is, this template spits out 27 incomprehensible errors (Examples: `Class, delegate, enum, interface or struct expected` on line 2, column 9; `} expected` on line 7, column 9; `method must have a return value` on line 15, column 18) and frankly, I don't even know where to start checking. My gut tells me when there's many weird errors, it's usually because of a couple simple things that the dev forgot to add/configure, but so far I haven't found anything that can help me. And nowhere in Google have I found a tutorial/example to generate a class via T4.

What do I want to generate? This:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace [TARGET_PROJECT_NAMESPACE]
{
    public class [TABLE_NAME]
    {
        public [FIELD_TYPE] [FIELD_NAME] { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You use parameters in your template. How are you going to pass them to template?

Comment: @evk I still haven't found how. I know that [VS provides a templating host](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4676347/1502310) I might be able to use.

Comment: Well that means you don't need to generate any output in design time. Those errors are produced because VS tries to transform your template at design time but that makes no sense. So right click your template, go to Properties and delete "Custom Tool". Note that your template still might be wrong (for example you use TableField without namespace), but that is another story.

Comment: ...and here comes the question: maybe I should discard T4 and use good old CodeDOM? My biggest worry is that my VSPackage can add my generated classes to the target project without problems.

Comment: I have no experience with using T4 templates in VS addins. I usually use them to inspect some code via reflection and generate yet another code in _design time_ (so no parameters). In this case (design time generation) it is very useful. In any other case... doubt that. So I'd say use whatever feels more convenient to you. If you decide to use T4 templates still - at least install VS addin which provides syntax highlighting there.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, can't add comment - still have no "50 reputation".

First of all - you need to refer to the namespace where TableField and other parts you using in the template are defined. Add <#@ import namespace="your.namnespace" #>.

Second - you want to have a lot of "using" statements in generated code - you need to put them into template as text.

About VSPackage - just remember that you have two stages - template compilation and code generation and there are two custom tools to do first or both stages. Most likely you need template compilation on development stage and template execution when package are used.

Hint : If template didn't do what it suppose to do - simplify a template to basic - let him generate the same static code again and again.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on your `.tt` file and make sure the value for your `Custom Tool` is set to `TextTemplatingFilePreProcessor`.

The boilerplate code when creating a new template should generate you a class - so for instance if you named your template `StackOverflowTemplate.tt`, then you should have a class named `StackOverflowTemplate` as well.

You can instantiate the `StackOverflowTemplate` class to add the parameters to your template like so:

**Program.cs**

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TableField> fields = new List<TableField>();

        StackOverflowTemplate sft = new StackOverflowTemplate();
        sft.Session = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        sft.Session.Add("_namespace", "TargetProjectNamespace");
        sft.Session.Add("className", "ClassName");
        sft.Session.Add("fields", fields);
        sft.Initialize();
        string output = sft.TransformText();
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

**StackOverflowTemplate.tt**

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ parameter name="_namespace" type="System.String" #>
<#@ parameter name="className" type="System.String" #>
<#@ parameter name="fields" type="System.Collections.Generic.List<TableField>" #>
namespace <#= _namespace #>
{
    public class <#= className #>
    {
        <#
            foreach (TableField campo in fields)
            {

            }
        #>
    }
}
```