# T4 template NullReferenceException when using parameter directive

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, t4

I am trying to implement an application that can process T4 templates.

I have implemented an Custom Text Template Host as shown in this article:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126579.aspx

I can run a simple template like this, and it works fine with both C# code and the include directive:

```
    <#@ template debug="true" #>
    <#@ include file="includehello.txt" #>  
    Some text.
    <# for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { #>
        //Line <#= i #>
    <# } #>
```

But, as soon as i try to use the "parameter" directive, i get a NullReferenceException.

```
    <#@ template debug="true" #>
    <#@ parameter type="System.String" name="worldParam" #>
    Hello <#=worldParam#>
```

The code that runs the template looks like this:

```
CustomCmdLineHost host = new CustomCmdLineHost();
Engine engine = new Engine();
host.TemplateFileValue = "HelloWorldTemplate.tt";           
//Read the text template.  
string input = File.ReadAllText(templateFileName);
host.Session = host.CreateSession();           
// Add parameter values to the Session:  
host.Session["worldParam"] = "world";
//Transform the text template.  
string output = engine.ProcessTemplate(input, host);
//Save the result
string outputFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(templateFileName);
outputFileName = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(templateFileName), outputFileName);
outputFileName = outputFileName + "1" + host.FileExtension;
File.WriteAllText(outputFileName, output, host.FileEncoding);
```

I suspect that the parameter values are never transferred into the engine, so the question is :

How do I transfer parameter values to the engine?

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4402011/t4-template-and-run-time-parameters) that uses `host.Initialize();` but that seems to be for precompiled templates and the `Initialize` method is not implemented in the example article. Neither is the `CreateSession();` I implemented that as described in that article.

P.S. 
In order to get the code from the article to work, i had to add the Nuget Package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis`, in addition to adding the mentioned references to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.15.0` and `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Interfaces.15.0`.

I am using VS2017. Target framework : .Net Framework 4.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `ITextTemplatingSessionHost` interface in addition to `ITextTemplatingEngineHost`. Class signature must be

```
public class CustomCmdLineHost : ITextTemplatingEngineHost, ITextTemplatingSessionHost
```

Comment: Excellent.  It was the missing ITextTemplatingSessionHost that solved it.
Thanks a lot for your help.